# Using a large QGraphicsScene, and not having QGraphicsView try to show everything

Tags: qt5

I'm trying to write something like a graph/spline editor using QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene, and I'm running into a problem that's basically the opposite of FitInView.

I want to be able to create a large QGraphicsScene (I know in advance how many "units" long my spline can be), and be able to arbitrarily pan over the QGraphicsItems, including looking at parts of the scene that are empty.

The problem I'm running into is that as soon as I set the size of my QGraphicsScene to as large as I want (around 20k or so), my whole main window is resized to cover my whole monitor (and some more), and I can't figure out how to have the graph (a bunch of QGraphicRect/Path items) remain the same size regardless of the underlying scene size, and be able to use scroll bars to pan over the whole thing.

Comment: I managed to get the desired effect by using QGraphicsView::setSceneRect to only display a portion of the scene, and then calling setSceneRect again when I wanted to pan the view.

Comment: Oh, and a second interesting observation. My view wasn't part of any layout, but once I stuck it inside a grid layout, then it didn't resize to a crazy size, so I might not even need the calls to setSceneRect..